# MySQL: Create table if not exist always appending data instead of skip creating table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have a table 'table1' and want to create another table, but store it in memory (engine=memory), with data from table1.

In my test server SQL works as expected - create the table once, put data in it from 'table1' and next time just skips insertion, because table 'mem_table' already exists.

In production server SQL is unexpected - it's create table 'mem_table', insert data from 'table1'. Every run it's inserting data again and again.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mem_table` (
`f1` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`f2` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
`f3` varchar(100) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`f1`),
KEY `f3` (`f3`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 SELECT NULL f1, f2, f3 FROM table1;
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the server not having enough memory to keep the table in storage

Comment: @BryanZwicker - I found an error "[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: The table 'mem_table' is full" in bdname.err file, but thought the reason is always appending data. Do you know a solution?

Comment: Have you looked at these possibilities? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/full-table.html

Comment: @BryanZwicker Thank you, it's seems the problem is in max_heap_table_size limit.

Comment: Awesome.  I'll convert my comment to an answer for the sake of people who come across this question in the future, if you wouldn't mind accepting when I post

Comment: @BryanZwicker Increasing max_heap_table_size didn't help (table is only 2mb size, and i set max_heap_table_size=64M).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior, as [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html) says, is version dependent.

So, the solution is not using "IF NOT EXISTS" in CREATE TABLE. And if the table is exists, mysql just return error and didn't insert data again and again.

```
CREATE TABLE `mem_table` (
`f1` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`f2` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
`f3` varchar(100) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`f1`),
KEY `f3` (`f3`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 SELECT NULL f1, f2, f3 FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered through our comments to your question:

It seems to be an issue with the memory not being allocated for the table.

Take a look through the common issues for memory-based table storage for MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/full-table.html

Comment: As i discover, the problem was in different version behavior and not depends on memory allocation size. I post a solution as an answer. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! Sorry I wasn't able to help some more :)